# Parsing a HTML page with Bash

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to write a Bash script that will extract informations from a HTML page (using `wget`).
I know my informations will be between `<h*>` tags, but is there a nice way to get those ?

To be more precise let's have an example :

> < h1>header1< /h1>
>      < h2>header2< /h2>
>      < h2>otherHeader2< /h2>
>   < h1>lastHeader1< /h1>
>      < h2>lastHeader2< /h2>

I'd like to extract "otherHeader2", a.k.a. the second (but it could be anywhere) header afer the header1.

Comment: It could be done, but it would be somewhat painful, I think.  If it were me, I'd use another scripting language, such as perl, python, or PHP, which can be run like a Bash script by using the proper shebang (hashbang); ie `#! /usr/bin/python` for a python script.  You may even find existing code for one of those, and it might be useful to learn the languages.

Comment: What about using `sed` or `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a simple python script that will parse your html and put all the values into a list and print it out. You can either write the rest of your script in python, or call this script from python, or plug this short code as a snippet in bash. Check out the examples below.

**test.html**

```
< h1>header1< /h1>
< h2>header2< /h2>
< h2>otherHeader2< /h2>
< h1>lastHeader1< /h1>
< h2>lastHeader2< /h2>
```

**parse_header.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re
print re.findall(r'< h\d>(.*)< /h\d>', sys.stdin.read())
```

**script can be called from bash**

```
cat test.html | parse_header.py
```

**python code can be put into bash script**

```
cat test.html | python -c "import sys, re;print re.findall(r'< h\d>(.*)< /h\d>', sys.stdin.read())"
```

the last option I believe is not very readable in your case. It makes more sense if you have some simple code where it's not worth putting it in it's own script.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1524545

Answer (score 3):

You should never parse html with regular expressions. Always use a proper html or xml parser. For example, using [xmlstarlet](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/xmlstarlet):

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//h2[2]' html.html 
otherHeader2
```